# Find points that are on two elliptic curves in $F_p$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, elliptic-curves

I have some basic cryptography question but I don't know if my calculations are not overcomplicated and if there's some simpler solution. Following algorithm is explained [here](https://youtu.be/yqHg0On0SKI?t=1271).

### Problem

There are two elliptic curves in $F_5$ with equations:

a) $y^2 = x^3 + 2x + 1 \pmod{5}$

b) $y^2 = x^3 + x + 1 \pmod{5}$

Find points that are in these two eliptic curves.

My approach is to determine points on these eliptic curves separately and then check for duplicates.

### Determining quadratic residue in $\mod{5}$

For every value in $\mod{5}$ calculate square for it, so

$
(\pm 1)^2 \pmod{5} = 1 \\
(\pm 2)^2 \pmod{5} = 4 \\
(\pm 3)^2 \pmod{5} = 9 \pmod{5} = 4 \\
(\pm 4)^2 \pmod{5} = 16 \pmod{5} = 1 \\
$

So our quadratic residue set is $QR = \{1, 4 \}$

### Determining points in a)

Equation is:
$
y^2 = x^3 + 2x + 1 \pmod{5}
$

Let's build table:

[image: table a]

1. In column $x$ we have all possible $x$.
2. In second column we calculate curve equation.
3. In third column we check if value is quadratic residue. So we check if its in $QR$. There is also option to check this with Euler theorem. For $y=3$ we check if $y^{(p-1)/2} \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$ so $3^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{5}$ is false because $3^2 \pmod{5} = 4$.
4. For all quadratic residues we calculate square roots. We can get them from step where we determined quadratic residues. For example we have $1$ for $1^2$ and $4^2$. So $1$ and $4$ are square roots of $1$.

So points on this elliptic curve are:

$(0, 1)$, $(0, 4)$, $(1, 2)$, $(1, 3)$, $(3, 2)$, $(3, 3)$

### Determining points in b)

Equation is:
$
y^2 = x^3 + x + 1 \pmod{5}
$

Let's build table:

[image]

So points on this eliptic curve are:

$(0, 1)$, $(0, 4)$, $(2, 1)$, $(2, 4)$, $(3, 1)$, $(3, 4)$, $(4, 2)$, $(4, 3)$.

### Result

Points $(0, 1)$ and $(0, 4)$ are on these two functions.

#### Checking if correct

[I've found website that generate points for given EC.](https://graui.de/code/elliptic2/) Solution that I've found is correct. Is there faster way to found these points?

#### EC a)

[image]

#### EC b)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are working on the same field for both the curves. To get the **common points** $(x_0,y_0)$ that lie on both the curves, you just need to to equate the following (think in terms of intersection of two curves)
\begin{align*}
y_0^2 =x_0^3+2x_0+1 &\equiv x_0^3+x_0+1 \pmod{5}\\
x_0 & \equiv 0 \pmod{5}.
\end{align*}
Thus $x_0=0$. Now this gives us that $y_0^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{5}$, which has only two solutions, namely $y_0=1,4$. Thus the common points are $(0,1)$ and $(0,4)$ and $\color{blue}{\text{the point at infinity } \mathcal{O}}$.

**Note:** If the task was to find the points on each curve separately, then what you did would be a good approach.